# Is this a standard numbering scheme for logical CPUs?

Tags: linux, cpu, core, logical-processor

This is a listing from Ubuntu 23.10 on AMD Ryzen 5 7640U:

```
paul@box4x4:~$ lscpu -ae
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ       MHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4971.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  1    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 5121.0000 400.0000 1576.8660
  2    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 5425.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  3    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 5275.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  4    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  5    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  6    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4971.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  7    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 5121.0000 400.0000 2696.6760
  8    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 5425.0000 400.0000 1395.6820
  9    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 5275.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 10    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000 2729.0950
 11    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 5579.0000 400.0000  400.0000
```

The CPU has 6 physical and 12 logical cores (hyperthreading). The mapping of logical CPUs to physical cores is: 0, 1, ..., 5, 0, 1, ..., 5. Is this a standard? For some reason, I was expecting 0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 5, 5 mapping. I can see that the observed mapping is easier for system management when you switch multithreading on and off. Is there another reason for this mapping choice?

Comment: ok, so this one is pretty opinion-based. I personally suspect that lscpu was expanded at some point to display logical threads, and at that time a decision was made to append the new code after the existing output functionality, such that the application by defaults sorts such that physical cores are listed first, followed by logical cores.

Comment: @FrankThomas I was assuming that CPU# listed by lscpu is the same as the one used by commands like cset and taskset and consistent across Linux utilities. Is that right?

Comment: Its as likely that the kernel puts them in that order. I'm just saying that some choices are more or less arbitrary, and may have no real rhyme/reason than "it was easier with the code we have" or it fits a particular dev's style.